# Iframe links stop loading if src is occupied

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a simple iframe:

```
<iframe name="eurosp" src="" width="100%" height="470px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allow="fullscreen" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

and a bunch of links that i want to load on click inside the iframe:

```
<p><a class="button-30" target="eurosp" href="link1">[ link 1 ]</a></p>
<p><a class="button-30" target="eurosp" href="link2">[ link 2 ]</a></p>
<p><a class="button-30" target="eurosp" href="link3">[ link 3 ]</a></p>
```

When i click the first time on link 1 or link 2 or link 3 it opens properly inside the iframe. But after that, when i want to change, for example from link 1 (already open in iframe) to link 2 (so i want link 2 to open inside iframe replacing link 1) does not work. Instead link 1 stays open inside iframe and link 2 or 3 keeps all the time opening in new tab. Same if i try with link 2 first. It opens properly inside iframe but when i try link 1 or 3 they keep opening in new tab and not inside the iframe.

What am i doing wrong? And if there is no simple explanation (which i would prefer) is there any simple script that empties src before i insert the new link?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry. I had to explain my "it does not work". Actually it works but keeps opening in new tab instead of inside the iframe. So there is no error in the console.

Comment: @Ouroborus I'm unable to reproduce the problem. I can go back and forth between different URLs in the iframe.